# How to install route automatically when a down interface comes to RUNNING

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have some static routes in my Linux system (Fedora) and I placed those static routes in the location `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` so that they can be executed every time system boots up. So far everything is working fine, but if the interface goes down all installed static routes will be deleted automatically.

Can anyone tell me that how to add those deleted routes automatically when down interface comes up again?

Thanks in advance,
Sudhir

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn a process that calls `tail -f /var/log/messages` (or /var/adm/messages, depending on your OS) and `grep` for the network interface you wish to monitor.  Or, periodically check the file by polling.

Comment: Hi Danny , Thanks for your answer/help. But this involves lot of overhead so i used exesting linux tool called "netplugd", which fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tool called **netplugd (network cable hotplug management daemon)**, which helped me to achieve above requirement. 
To use this tool we have to follow below steps

1. update "/etc/netplug/netplugd.conf" file with the interface names that you want to monitor ( The netplugd daemon monitor these interfaces and notifies us)
2. Edit '/etc/netplug.d/netplug" file according to your requirements
3. Now start the netplugd daemon ex: /etc/init.d/netplugd start

More information is available in man page of netplugd **(man 8 netplugd)**

Thanks,
Sudhir